# Asp.Net ListView ItemUpdating does not set OldValues when using UpdateItem()

Tags: asp.net, listview, updating, optimistic-concurrency

I don't know why the OldValues of the ItemUpdating eventargs is not being set when I try to update items using Listview.UpdateItem method.

OldValues is always set when I use the normal procedure of entering in edit mode and then clicking an "update" commmand button.

It seems that because I am triggering the update via UpdateItem method, things do not work the same way...

I am using an ObjectDataSourde with ConflictDetection="CompareAllValues" in conjunction with EF and also want to use the oldvalues in order to update only the fields that changed.

Do you guys have any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks

Marcelo